# Python Variable Not Working In If Statement

Tags: python, pycharm, xlrd, python-3.7

I am using selenium to loop through URL's from a txt file and grab a specific serial number that is listed on each URL. Then I want to reference an excel file and find the cell next to the serial number and print that value.

My problem is when I am storing the serial number in a variable, it is not working in my if statement. If i replace the variable with an actual serial number, it runs as intended. Why isn't the stored variable working in my code?

Here is my intended code, where i receive no output:

```
 with open('Url.txt') as links:
        for line in links:
            time.sleep(3)
            driver.get(line)
            editpage = driver.find_elements_by_link_text('Edit this device')
            for page in editpage:
                time.sleep(1)
                editurl = page.get_attribute('href')
                driver.get(editurl)
                Devicesn = driver.find_elements_by_id('device.name')
                for sn in Devicesn:
                    serialnumber = sn.get_property('value')
                    wb = xlrd.open_workbook('C:\doc.xls')
                    for sheet in wb.sheets():
                        for row_num in range(sheet.nrows):
                            row_value = sheet.row_values(row_num)
                            if row_value[1] == serialnumber:
                                print(row_value[0])
```

If i replace serialnumber with a number, i get the cell value i'm looking for:

```
    with open('Url.txt') as links:
        for line in links:
            time.sleep(3)
            driver.get(line)
            editpage = driver.find_elements_by_link_text('Edit this device')
            for page in editpage:
                time.sleep(1)
                editurl = page.get_attribute('href')
                driver.get(editurl)
                Devicesn = driver.find_elements_by_id('device.name')
                for sn in Devicesn:
                    serialnumber = sn.get_property('value')
                    wb = xlrd.open_workbook('C:\doc.xls')
                    for sheet in wb.sheets():
                        for row_num in range(sheet.nrows):
                            row_value = sheet.row_values(row_num)
                            if row_value[1] == 6216295237: #replaced serialnumber
                                print(row_value[0])
```

This gives me my intended value. Why doesn't my serialnumber variable work here? Thanks!

**EDIT:**  Thank you all for the  replies. To hopefully help this make more sense I printed the serialnumber variable and it's length.

```
serialnumber = sn.get_property('value')
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('C:\doc.xls')
for sheet in wb.sheets():
    for row_num in range(sheet.nrows):
        row_value = sheet.row_values(row_num)
        print(serialnumber)
        print(len(serialnumber))
        time.sleep(60)
        if row_value[1] == serialnumber:
            print(row_value[0])
```

Output is: 6216295237
           10

VS

```
#serialnumber = sn.get_property('value')
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('C:\doc.xls')
for sheet in wb.sheets():
    for row_num in range(sheet.nrows):
        row_value = sheet.row_values(row_num)
        if row_value[1] == 6216295237:
            print(row_value[0])
```

Output is: G47

Comment: What is the value of the variable `serialnumber`? Did you try to print it before using?

Comment: What do you mean by `it is not working in my if statement`? Does the program crash with an error? Or just not print out anything?

Comment: @DYZ - Thank you for your reply! I printed the variable  in my edit. Hopefully that makes sense!

Comment: @bunbun - Sorry i didn't clarify. It doesn't print out anything. The program completes without error.

Comment: The value returned by `sn.get_property` is a string. You must convert it to a number before the comparison

Comment: @DYZ - That was it! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's more likely you are not getting the correct value or no value at all in this line

```
serialnumber = sn.get_property('value')
```

You can try printing this variable to see what you are getting.
Maybe the texts you are looking for are not really in the `'value'` property of elements with id `'device.name'`.

Besides that, ids are usually unique so there should be only one in the whole page. Maybe `'device.name'` is actually a class? Can't tell without the page source.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I made an edit above to add more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Try to print your variables:

```
print(serialnumber)
```

and

```
print(row_value[1])
```

then, check if they are the same.

Edit: Looking at the documentation, you should try to use `get_attribute()` instead of `get_property`

Comment: Hi @klagos! You seem to be new to SO. Please note that debugging instruction don't make a good answer on their own. An answer should contain a solution. What you wrote should actually go into the comment section. I am aware that new users have limitations and commenting might not be allowed for you yet.

Comment: @KlausD I actually put a solution on my answer at the Edit part.

Comment: @klagos Hey, thanks for the reply. I made an edit hopefully that makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

User DYZ answered this problem in a comment.

The value returned by sn.get_property is a string. You must convert it to a number before the comparison – DYZ

I simply used this to convert it:

```
serial = int(serialnumber)
```